# Fixing Jquery Responsive Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to fix my code for a responsive menu. The problem is whenever when I click on the About menu/button. The sub-menu for the gallery appears and not the about sub-menu. Here is the code I'm working on at the moment

**HTML**

```
<div class="container12">
    <div class="column12">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">About3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.sub-menu').hide(function(){
        $('nav ul li').click(function(){
       $('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(500);

        })
    })


})
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{margin-top:10px; display:block;}
nav ul li{display:inline;  background-color:beige; float:left}
nav ul li a{display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding:10px 20px; position:relative}

.display_menu{display:block !important}

ul.sub-menu{position:absolute; display:none}
ul.sub-menu li{display:block; float:none }



@media only screen and (max-width: 360px){

    nav ul li{display:block; float:none}
    ul.sub-menu{position:static;}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your event handler is causing **all** ul.sub-menu items to slide down. You need to specify that you only want the children of the element clicked to slide down:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul.sub-menu').hide(function(){
      $('nav ul li').click(function(){
          $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(500);
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

The line I changed is `$(this).children('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(500);`. In the event handler, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event and the `children` function finds its descendants filtered by the ul.sub-menu criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and also the added knowledge regarding "this" and "children" functions.

Answer (score 1):

See an updated JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uagv8n1r/)

Your Javascript was looking for the first `ul.submenu` in the tree of elements, which is the Gallery `ul.sub-menu`. You need to tell it to look for the `ul.sub-menu` as a child to the `li` that you just clicked:

```
$('nav ul li').click(function(){
    $('ul.sub-menu', this).slideToggle(500); // 'this' looks at what you just clicked
});
```

You also had your `hide()` function to hide all the `ul.sub-menu`'s on the page surrounding the function to *show* your sub menu. This means when you click to show a sub menu, it would show it, then hide it immediately afterwards. I changed that to a solo function which hides all of the sub menus on document load only. Here is what you JS should look like now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
   $('nav ul li').click(function(){
      $('ul.sub-menu', this).slideToggle(500);
   });
});
```